# Redirect to Home page if URL not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, url-routing

**For following scenario, I have to redirect to home page if entered url not found.**

When user try to access page which is not available, it should redirect to home page or error page.
**CODE:**
*

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Header />
          <div className="app-container">
            <Switch>
              {routes.map(
                ({ key, path, crumbs, renderComponent }) => {
                  return (
                    <Route key={key} path={path}>
                      {renderComponent(crumbs)}
                    </Route>
                  )
                }
              )}
              <Redirect exact from="/" to="/merchants" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <div className="footer-wrapper">
            <div className="footer">
              <footer max-width="1920"></footer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another `Redirect` that handles any route path that wasn't handled above it by a `Route` or `Redirect` component rendering on a more specific path.

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map(({ key, path, crumbs, renderComponent }) => (
    <Route key={key} path={path}>
      {renderComponent(crumbs)}
    </Route>
  ))}
  <Redirect exact from="/" to="/merchants" />
  <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

Since it seems the `"/merchants"` route is your default homepage you can remove the `exact` and `to` props and handle any route path that wasn't handled previously.

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map(({ key, path, crumbs, renderComponent }) => (
    <Route key={key} path={path}>
      {renderComponent(crumbs)}
    </Route>
  ))}
  <Redirect to="/merchants" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It's working for me. But This routing is also redirecting me if I try to access following url pattern :
/merchants/:id'

Comment: @Akshayphalphale You would need to explicitly render a route higher up in the `Switch` that *could* match a `"/merchants/:id"` path.